# После "но"(,) перед "если"(,)... После лета(,) перед зимой(,)

Tags: пунктуация

> После "но"(**,**) перед "если"(**,**) запятую ставим при наличии паузы между
> союзами и не ставим, если паузы нет!
>
> После лета(**,**) перед  зимой(**,**) нужно уже начинать готовиться!

Нужны ли запятые в этих предложениях? И где?

Comment: Без пауз вообще не звучит.

Comment: А у вас вопросы всё сложнее становятся, смотрю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что могу интересное рассказать:
1) очень сложно придумать пример, где могла бы быть только одна запятая, но у меня получалось;
2) но это надо реально постараться, вряд ли так может получиться само по себе (у кого-либо);
3) а теперь как это сделать: обстоятельства должны быть равноправными, не уступать друг другу в плане важности;
4) у Розенталя вообще нет такого, оно не используется, из-за того что это чрезвычайная редкость.

Второй пример у вас искусственный, а вот как раз такая ситуация, как в первом, у меня была, вроде бы тогда решил переформулировать, чтобы лучше звучало (а о звучании будет далее).

Во втором примере надобно уточнение:
*После лета, [а именно] перед зимой, нужно уже начинать готовиться!*

И вот вроде бы в первом примере есть равноправие и, казалось бы, это тот редкий случай... Но нет, в таких случаях загвоздка в стилистике. Равноправные обстоятельства очень плохо звучат, и высокая сложность как раз заключается в том, чтобы пример был удачным в плане стилистики. А здесь нужно связать два обстоятельства в одну ситуацию союзом И.

Чтобы запятых не было, обстоятельства должны хоть как-то соотноситься, например: *в селе возле реки* (река в селе).

Comment: Примечание: сказанное касается лишь обстоятельств места и времени.